# XSL - transform hierarchical XML into Flat XML structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSL and I have been trying to flatten out an XML structure which is multiple levels deep. I had some success but have hit a wall. I am missing some nodes from the `Campaign_Product_Source_Group`. The nodes are `ITEM_GROUP_NAME`, `QUANTITY_AMOUNT` and `INCLUDED`.

Any help will be appreciated..

Here is my XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Offers>
    <Records>
        <Campaign_Product_Result>
            <TABLE_ID>8</TABLE_ID>
             <REC_TYPE>4</REC_TYPE>
        <REC_VALUE>GroupName</REC_VALUE>
        <PARAM>1</PARAM>
        <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
        <Campaign_Product_Result_Item>
            <TABLE_ID>8</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
            <REC_VALUE>987787</REC_VALUE>
            <PARAM/>
            <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
        </Campaign_Product_Result_Item>
        <Campaign_Product_Result_GTIN>
            <TABLE_ID>8</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
            <REC_VALUE>20054200000</REC_VALUE>
            <PARAM/>
            <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
        </Campaign_Product_Result_GTIN>
        </Campaign_Product_Result>
        <Campaign_Product_Source_Package>
            <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
            <QUANTITY_AMOUNT>Q1</QUANTITY_AMOUNT>
            <Campaign_Product_Source_Group>
                <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
                <REC_TYPE>4</REC_TYPE>
                <ITEM_GROUP_NAME>GroupName</ITEM_GROUP_NAME>
                <QUANTITY_AMOUNT>1</QUANTITY_AMOUNT>
                <INCLUDED>0</INCLUDED>
                <Campaign_Product_Source_Item>
                    <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
                    <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
                    <REC_VALUE>02100074434</REC_VALUE>
                    <PARAM/>
                    <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
                </Campaign_Product_Source_Item>
            </Campaign_Product_Source_Group>
        </Campaign_Product_Source_Package>
    </Records>
</Offers>
```

My XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">    
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template 
match="Campaign_Product_Result
[Campaign_Product_Result_Item|Campaign_Product_Result_GTIN]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::TABLE_ID)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::REC_TYPE)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::REC_VALUE)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::PARAM)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::COMPARE_TYPE)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Campaign_Product_Result_Item"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Campaign_Product_Result_GTIN"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Campaign_Product_Source_Package">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::TABLE_ID)]|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::REC_TYPE)]|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::QUANTITY_AMOUNT)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Campaign_Product_Source_Package"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Campaign_Product_Source_Package[Campaign_Product_Source_Group]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::TABLE_ID)]|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::REC_TYPE)]|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::ITEM_GROUP_NAME)]|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::QUANTITY_AMOUNT)]|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::INCLUDED)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Campaign_Product_Source_Group"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Campaign_Product_Source_Group
 [Campaign_Product_Source_Item]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::TABLE_ID)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::REC_TYPE)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::REC_VALUE)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::PARAM)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::COMPARE_TYPE)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Campaign_Product_Source_Item"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output:

```
<Offers>
    <Records>
        <Campaign_Product_Result>
            <TABLE_ID>8</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>4</REC_TYPE>
            <REC_VALUE>GroupName</REC_VALUE>
            <PARAM>1</PARAM>
            <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
        </Campaign_Product_Result>
        <Campaign_Product_Result_Item>
            <TABLE_ID>8</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
            <REC_VALUE>987787</REC_VALUE>
            <PARAM/>
            <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
        </Campaign_Product_Result_Item>
        <Campaign_Product_Result_GTIN>
            <TABLE_ID>8</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
            <REC_VALUE>20054200000</REC_VALUE>
            <PARAM/>
            <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
        </Campaign_Product_Result_GTIN>
        <Campaign_Product_Source_Package>
            <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
            <QUANTITY_AMOUNT>Q1</QUANTITY_AMOUNT>
        </Campaign_Product_Source_Package>
        <Campaign_Product_Source_Group>
            <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>4</REC_TYPE>
        </Campaign_Product_Source_Group>
        <Campaign_Product_Source_Item>
            <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
            <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
            <REC_VALUE>02100074434</REC_VALUE>
            <PARAM/>
            <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
        </Campaign_Product_Source_Item>
    </Records>
</Offers>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are missing because you didn't copy them in the appropriate template:

```
<xsl:template match="Campaign_Product_Source_Group
 [Campaign_Product_Source_Item]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::TABLE_ID)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::REC_TYPE)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::REC_VALUE)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::PARAM)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::COMPARE_TYPE)]|@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::ITEM_GROUP_NAME)]|@*"/>    <!-- added -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::QUANTITY_AMOUNT)]|@*"/>    <!-- added -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[(self::INCLUDED)]|@*"/>           <!-- added -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Campaign_Product_Source_Item/*"/>        <!-- moved inside xsl:copy -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I also moved the `Campaign_Product_Source_Item/*` elements in between the `xsl:copy` to flatten that. Change it back if you like it.

**The (snipped) output is:**

```
...
<Campaign_Product_Source_Group>
    <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
    <REC_TYPE>4</REC_TYPE>
    <ITEM_GROUP_NAME>GroupName</ITEM_GROUP_NAME>
    <QUANTITY_AMOUNT>1</QUANTITY_AMOUNT>
    <INCLUDED>0</INCLUDED>
    <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
    <REC_TYPE>0</REC_TYPE>
    <REC_VALUE>02100074434</REC_VALUE>
    <PARAM/>
    <COMPARE_TYPE>0</COMPARE_TYPE>
</Campaign_Product_Source_Group>
...
```